# Using cypress, measure page load time

Tags: typescript, performance, integration-testing, cypress

Im using cypress to test a website, I need a way to measure the amount of time that it takes to load or execute certain cypress commands. For example:

```
//var startTime = SomeStopwatchFunction();
cy.visit("/a website");
cy.get("Some item");
//cy.log(SomeStopwatchFunction - startTime);
```

I've tried using the `cy.clock()` but that returns 0. So I might be doing something wrong there. I've used `performance.now()` which kinda works but always returns the same value regardless of the load time. I've used `Date.getTime()` but that also returns 0. Its got to have something to do with how cypress executes the code but nothing seems to work.

Comment: cy.clock is used to control the system’s time and date. Take a look at this blog post as it may help you out: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/05/22/where-does-the-test-spend-its-time/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are measuring things that happen asynchronously on the Cypress queue, so you need to insert your timing commands in the queue as well, using `cy.wrap()`.

Otherwise they will execute before the page loads and give you a very small diff.

```js
const t0 = performance.now()
cy.visit("/a website");
cy.get("Some item");
cy.wrap(performance.now()).then(t1 => {   // this is now a queued command which will 
                                          // only run after the previous command
  cy.log(`Page load took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`);
})
```

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to time the page load is to use events provided.

That way you don't have to worry about `before()` hook code or other "housekeeping" commands that occur in the test setup.

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/#/users', {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    win.t0 = performance.now()
  },
  onLoad: (win) => {
    t1 = performance.now()
    cy.log(`Page load took ${t1 - win.t0} milliseconds.`)
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer (from user9161752) may lead to strange results. In my case the duration is about 5 seconds too high. It seems to me that `const t0 = performance.now()` is called before stuff in `beforeEach` runs, so the result contained the duration of the login process in my case.

So you also have to set the start time asynchronously. This works for me:

```
let start = 0;
cy.then(() => {
    start = performance.now();
});
cy.visit("/a website");
cy.get("Some item").then(() => {
    cy.log(`duration: ${performance.now() - start} ms`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a need to measure a page load time exactly after click, so I wrote the following code:

```js
cy.get(loginLoginBtn).should('exist').then(() => {
        const t0 = performance.now();

        cy.get(loginLoginBtn)
        .click()
        .location('pathname').should('eq', '/package_selection')
        .wait('@recentProfiles').its('response.statusCode')
        .should('eq', 200)
        .then(() => {
            const t1 = performance.now();
            const packagePageLoadTime = ((t1 - t0) / 1000);
            cy.log(`Page load took ${packagePageLoadTime} seconds.`)
            cy.writeFile(packagePageLoadFile, '[]', {flag: 'w+'});
            cy.readFile(packagePageLoadFile).then((writeTimeToFile) => {
                writeTimeToFile.push({dateOfExecution: executionDate, timeInSeconds: packagePageLoadTime});
                cy.writeFile(packagePageLoadFile, writeTimeToFile);
            });
            expect(packagePageLoadTime).to.be.lessThan(5);
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [cypress-timings](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-timings) that gives a general timing of each cypress commands. It's as easy a installing and adding the following into your `support/index.js`

```
import { commandTimings } from 'cypress-timings'
commandTimings()
```